# FFMPEG splitting an 8-channels WAV into 4 stereo WAV files

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I have a single WAV file containing 8 channels (it is NOT 7.1, all channels are full bandwidth) and I need to split it to 4 stereo WAV files.
Of course it is easy to split it into 8 mono files, and then pack them in pairs to 4 stereo files. But I am searching for a single command doing this in one step, as I am not allowed to use 5 different commands ...

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. I would suggest you need to define why you can't use 5 different commands, as it will provide additional context to your goal.

Comment: I don't know. I was just asked to provide a single-line command doing this task...

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found the answer. The correct command is this one:

```
C:\Temp>ffmpeg -i test.wav -map_channel 0.0.0 -map_channel 0.0.1 first.wav -map_channel 0.0.2 -map_channel 0.0.3 second.wav -map_channel 0.0.4 -map_channel 0.0.5 third.wav -map_channel 0.0.6 -map_channel 0.0.7 fourth.wav
```

Comment: thank you! I also found this: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try something along the lines of

```
ffmpeg -i whatever.wav -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -vn -c copy first.wav -map 0:2 -map 0:3 -vn -c copy second.wav -map 0:4 -map 0:5 -vn -c copy third.wav -map 0:6 -map 0:7 -vn -c copy fourth.wav
```

Comment: Thanks... But it does not work, it says:
Stream map '0:1' matches no streams.
To ignore this, add a trailing '?' to the map.

Comment: For being more precise, the command was:
C:\Temp\ffmpeg -i test.wav -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -vn -c copy first.wav -map 0:2 -map 0:3 -vn -c copy second.wav -map 0:4 -map 0:5 -vn -c copy third.wav -map 0:6 -map 0:7 -vn -c copy fourth.wav

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a 8 channel single-stream WAV, use

```
ffmpeg -i in.wav -filter_complex
          "[0]pan=stereo|c0=c0|c1=c1[a];
           [0]pan=stereo|c0=c2|c1=c3[b];
           [0]pan=stereo|c0=c4|c1=c5[c];
           [0]pan=stereo|c0=c6|c1=c7[d]"
       -map "[a]" first.wav
       -map "[b]" second.wav
       -map "[c]" third.wav
       -map "[d]" fourth.wav
```

Comment: Sorry, this is too long, I need a single-line command, as the one I did find and is shown above...
If I was allowed to use more lines, then I had followed the simple way, to first create 8 mono files, and then to pack them two by two...

Comment: It is a single line command. I have formatted it for readability.